# pycoingecko: how to get all market data for all coins?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coingecko

I am new to coding and am currently trying pull all market for all coins from `CoinGecko` using Python.

Using `pycoingecko`, I can use `cg.get_coins_list()` to get all coins and ids, and I can use `cg.get_coins_markets()` to get the top 250 coins, however I am struggling to get any more.

Any advice on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is too much data for a single `cg.get_coins_markets()` function call to get more than the top 250 coins. To get more coins, I think you can call the next top 250 coins, which can be accessed using the `page` parameter of the api (see the endpoint `/coins/markets` in the [documentation](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation) for more details)

```
cg.get_coins_markets(vs_currency='usd', page=2)
```

If you want to get more coins, simply increase the number passed in the `page` argument

```
cg.get_coins_markets(vs_currency='usd', page=3)
cg.get_coins_markets(vs_currency='usd', page=4)
cg.get_coins_markets(vs_currency='usd', page=5)
```